# When clicking on checkbox, error returned saying another element would receive the click

Tags: robotframework, element

When I run the robot framework code:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//span[contains(text(),'Add to Cart')]    10     
    Click Element    xpath=//div/input[@id='_wdmaf']
```

I get the error

```
20190423 14:05:32.525 : FAIL : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element 
<input tabindex="0" bh="CHKGAT" id="_wdmaf" type="checkbox" value="1" class="w-chk-native" hasaction="true"> is not clickable at point (311, 221). 
Other element would receive the click: <label bh="CHK" class="w-chk w-chk-dsize"></label>
```

The element I'm trying to click looks like this:

```
<td class="noWrap">
    <input tabindex="0" bh="CHKGAT" id="_wdmaf" type="checkbox" value="1" class="w-chk-native" hasaction="true">
    <label bh="CHK" class="w-chk w-chk-dsize"></label>
```

No matter how I try to change the selector, I keep getting that error.  It is a checkbox with no text that then selects all of the items in a shopping list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It very well may be the case the `label` element is supposed to be clicked by the user - after all, selenium complains it is overlapping the `input` one in the layout, so it may be placed there intentionally.

If for all intents and purposes clicking the `label` leads to the desired functional change on the page (selecting all elements), I would go with it. The target xpath would be something like:

```
//div/input[@id='_wdmaf']/following-sibling::label
```

That will select the `label` that follows the `input` and is on the same label in the hierarchy. If you want to be a bit more specific about it, you can suffix it with the condition `[@bh='CHK']`